# Jenkinsfile to checkout different repo and update a file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I  have 2 repos A and B. At the end of build A, I want to update a properties file in repo B with the build number of A

1. How can I checkout the **master** branch of **repo B** in repo A's Jenkinfile just for this stage(which is last) ?
2. After checkout, can I follow the steps
   mentioned below to update the file or is there any better way to
   achieve it?

**Jenkinsfile of repo A:**

```
        stage('Update properties file in repo B') {
            steps {
                script {
                        // how do I checkout master branch ofrepo B here?
                        sh "git config --global user.email jenkins@abc.com"
                        sh "git config --global user.name Jenkins"
                        sh(script: 'echo "repoA_VERSION=$BUILD_NUMBER" > version.properties', returnStdout: true).trim()
                        git add .
                        git commit -m "Updated version.properties file with ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call git step:

E.g.

```
git branch: 'your_branch', credentialsId: 'your_credentials', url: 'your_repo'
```

If you don't know identifier for your credentials, you can go to:

```
your_jenkins_server:8080/job/job_name/pipeline-syntax/
```

where job_name is any job in your server, and you will access to Pipeline Syntax, you can then configure your git checkout and generate command:
[image]

For number 2,
the code must be within sh command:

```
sh """git add .
      git commit -m "Updated version.properties file with ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
      git push
"""
```

A final recommendation, avoid using git add ., and add files individually or with a wildcard.

Comment: Should I mention the branch as `master` or `refs/heads/master`

Comment: branch must be specified as: master

Comment: got an error `git: 'branch:master,' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.` when I tried `sh 'git branch: 'your_branch', credentialsId: 'your_credentials', url: 'your_repo''`

Comment: ```git branch: 'your_branch', credentialsId: 'your_credentials', url: 'your_repo'``` must appear where you typed ```// how do I checkout master branch ofrepo B here?```

Comment: yes, I added it over there only and got the error `git: 'branch:master,' is not a git command. See 'git --help'`

Comment: Also, make sure to have git install on your master or slave and configure it at global tool configuration, or use JGIT. Have you tried the pipeline syntax? if git step appears, then git plugin is installed and you should have not issue.
Global tool configuration ```your_server:8080/configureTools/```
Pipeline syntax:
```your_jenkins_server:8080/job/job_name/pipeline-syntax/```

Comment: Ok, I see you surrounded branch with quotes, remove the quotes for branch, only for master: ```git branch: 'master', credentialsId: '****-****-****-*********', url: 'git@github.com:user_example/repo_example.git'```